# How browsable API works in django rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to know how django's browsable API works.

When I open browsable API with a browser, it renders a html page.
But when I fetch data from postman or any other service, it gives json data.

So how this works?
And, how can I do it without django rest framework.?

Answer (score 0):

From [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/).

> By default, the API will return the format specified by the headers, which in the case of the browser is HTML. The format can be specified using ?format= in the request, so you can look at the raw JSON response in a browser by adding ?format=json to the URL. There are helpful extensions for viewing JSON in Firefox and Chrome.